# Get path in different project in solution asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 projects in my solution, my API project and my project that I send info to API.

this its in my controller on project that sent to API:

```
            pic = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);//image name
            path = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~"), @"WebApi1/Employee/"));//path in my project api
            path2 = Path.Combine(path, Path.GetFileName(pic));//try combine path folder in api + image name

            file.SaveAs(path2);//try safe image in folder api
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                file.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
                byte[] array = ms.GetBuffer();
            }
```

but this says that does not recognize path.

[image]

Comment: it i am not mistaken it must be accessed as "webApi1/conteent/employee"

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access files in another application and `Server.MapPath` will maps a virtual path to a physical path on the server for the current application.

> `Server.MapPath("~")` returns the physical path to the root of the application

If this two application will be deployed in the same web application it will work on the server, If not you need to create a configration for image folder that specifies the full path you need to use.